# What are the different Madhabs created by people in Islam?

Tags: sects

Islam is one, but we hear about different Madhabs. I would like to gain information regarding various madhab.

- How many ?
- How were they formed ?
- What common things bind them together ?

Please let me know.

Comment: What ever is not there in [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madhhab#Established_schools) plz try to focus on that part in individual questions...